# How the mode of signal change by low-pass filtering

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution, signal-processing

For an arbitrary signal that has multiple peaks, I want to know how peaks are shifted by low-pass filtering (you can assume any simple one).

Any theory related to this or the way to derive the bound?

I appreciate in advance, thanks!

Comment: The peaks will be shifted according to the frequencies that comprise them and the group delay of the filter. However, after filtering, some peaks might not exist any more. Since peaks tend to be associated with high frequency content, a low-pass filter could potentially remove them all.